# Do folder names affect Team Foundation security behaviour?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am adding new files to TFS via the TF commandline application as part of a build process.

Multiple files are added to the workspace, and subsequently checked in previously without issue.
However, new files have been added to a folder in the tree called 'Secure' and when the build attempts to add these files I get a slightly different message from the TF output.
It successfully adds the first file, but then hangs on the second.
The security of the folder on the disk is the same as other folders that add correctly.

The powershell command used is:

```
$p = Start-Process $process -ArgumentList add [PATH] -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

The normal output from TF for an add operation is :

Adding D:\Builds\9\Core\[BuildName]\Sources\[Project]\core\packages.config*
   packages.config

However in the 'Secure' folder it returns this:

```
Adding D:\Builds\9\Core\\[BuildName]\Sources\\[Project]\core\Secure\NewPage.ascx    
Secure:    
NewPage.ascx
```

Note the extra output stating `"Secure:"`

The folder security in TFS is the same as the folders that accept add operations correctly (inherited from parent folders). I haven't been able to find anything in the command line documentation regarding this behaviour.

Comment: What if the subdirectory was called `Foo`, or `Bar`?  This looks like the standard output when you do a recursive add and it pends adds on a file in a subfolder, no?